# How can I specify the directory in which Start-Job will run?

Tags: powershell

The desired outcome of this effort is to run a simple .bat script as a PowerShell job. It appears to work correctly except for the error message at the end of the output.

From where does PowerShell get the directory in which to start a job? The location it uses is my default Windows "documents" directory. My organization does not permit use of the "My Documents" directory on the local disk.

Can I specify the initial directory in which Start-Job should run? If so, how?

```
PS C:\src\powershell> Get-Content .\sayhi.bat
SET EXITCODE=0
ECHO hi
EXIT /B %EXITCODE%

PS C:\src\powershell> Start-Job -ScriptBlock {& "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" "/C", "C:\src\powershell\sayhi.bat"}

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
1      Job1            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            & "C:\Windows\System32...


PS C:\src\powershell> Get-Job

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
1      Job1            BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            & "C:\Windows\System32...

PS C:\src\powershell> Receive-Job -Id 1 -Keep

20:15:27.33  C:\Windows
C:>SET EXITCODE=0

20:15:27.33  C:\Windows
C:>ECHO hi
hi

20:15:27.35  C:\Windows
C:>EXIT /B 0
'\\AHOST\USERS\pwatson\My Documents'
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ('\\AHOST\USERS\pwatson\My Documents':String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : localhost

CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the initial directory in a `ScriptBlock` passed to the `-InitializationScript` parameter...

```
Start-Job `
    -InitializationScript { Set-Location $Env:TEMP } `
    -ScriptBlock { & "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" "/C", "C:\src\powershell\sayhi.bat" }
```

...or simply before you call your batch file in the `ScriptBlock` you're already using...

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Set-Location $Env:TEMP;
    & "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" "/C", "C:\src\powershell\sayhi.bat"
}
```